# Truncar a dos decimales en kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Buenas estoy haciendo un codigo para redondear un precio a dos decimales pero cuando lo intento me sale el siguiente error

**Process: com.example.escanergolosinas, PID: 7145
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "33,24"**

El codigo que uso es el siguiente

```
Precio *= 0.95
    Precio = DecimalFormat("#.##").format(Precio).toDouble()
```

Y no se porque puede ser este error porque en otra parte del codigo uso el mismo codigo con la misma variable y no da problemas

Precio es esta variable

```
    private var Precio = 0.0
```

Y se rellena de la siguiente manera cogiendolo de una base de datos de firebase

```
Precio = document.getDouble("Precio")!!
```